# How to Use Tkinter Entry like raw_input

Tags: python, tkinter, raw-input

I'm trying to create a GUI for a TCP socket, the main function asks for the server address and wait an answer to proceed. This is the code

```
print("Welcome to TCP Socket")
address = raw_input("Insert server address: ")
print("Connectiong to " + address)
...
```

Now I have a entry from Tkinter called iTxt to get user input and I use the method get() to get the input but the result isn't the same as a `raw_input()` and I can't figure how to emulate `raw_input`. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Exactly what functionality of `raw_input` is missing from the `tk.Entry` widget that you wish to emulate?

Comment: @martineau: my guess is that the OP wants a callable that blocks until the user enters a string.

Comment: exactly what i want, if i use get() the function go on even if the entry is empty. i want that the function waits for the pression of Return on the keyboard by the user

Answer (score 4):

If this is running inside an existing GUI, you can create a modal dialog with a Toplevel, using the method `wait_window` to block until the window is destroyed. If you want to use a popup window in an otherwise non-GUI program, you can create a little self-contained tkinter program in a function which returns a value when the root window is destroyed.

In either case, the technique is to wait for the window to be destroyed, and then fetch the value that was in the window. Since the window will have been destroyed, you must use a `StringVar` since it won't be destroyed along with the window.

Here is an example that assumes no GUI is already running:

```
import tkinter as tk

def gui_input(prompt):

    root = tk.Tk()
    # this will contain the entered string, and will
    # still exist after the window is destroyed
    var = tk.StringVar()

    # create the GUI
    label = tk.Label(root, text=prompt)
    entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
    label.pack(side="left", padx=(20, 0), pady=20)
    entry.pack(side="right", fill="x", padx=(0, 20), pady=20, expand=True)

    # Let the user press the return key to destroy the gui 
    entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: root.destroy())

    # this will block until the window is destroyed
    root.mainloop()

    # after the window has been destroyed, we can't access
    # the entry widget, but we _can_ access the associated
    # variable
    value = var.get()
    return value

print("Welcome to TCP Socket")
address = gui_input("Insert server address:")
print("Connecting to " + address)
```

If you already have a GUI that is running, you can replace `tk.Tk()` with `tk.Toplevel()` to create a popup window, and then use `.wait_window()` rather than `.mainloop()` to wait for the window to be destroyed.

Comment: this could be a valid possibility but it would be too obsolete because this program needs an input of the user to get an answer like in a shell

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer: I don't understand your comment. When you call this function, it will pop up a window and wait for a user to enter some data. Isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer: then I have no idea what you want. You ask how to emulate `raw_input` with a GUI. Well, `raw_input` waits for the user to enter something, and in a GUI, a dialog waits for you to input something. If that's not what you want, you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
from tkinter import *
#this is the main window

window = Tk()
#here is our function


def entry_input(prompt):
    #our frame to encapsulate our prompt and entry
    frame = Frame(window)
    #our label with our prompt
    label = Label(frame, text=prompt)
    #the variable to store the text
    text = StringVar()
    #the entry widget
    entry = Entry(window, textvariable=text)
    #show our label and entry
    label.pack()
    entry.pack()
    #return the text provided by the user
    return text.get()

my_input = entry_input("provide some text:")
#do something with the text 

#finally run the application
window.mainloop()
```

The explanation for this code is in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot completely emulate raw_input in tkInter, since tkInter is event-driven. When you use raw_input, program execution blocks until you provide input and press enter. When you use get (), you'll get input anyhow, even if your entry is still empty.

The simplest way to get some kind of blocking behaviour is using a modal dialog. But the best way to go is to dive into event driven programming. If something is input (and probably OK pressed), an event is triggered by TkInter. As a reaction on this event you call an event handler function processing the input.

All GUI's use event driven programming, so it pays of to invest (quite) some time.

Comment: I think _"You cannot completely emulate raw_input in tkInter, since tkInter is event-driven"_ is false. You absolutely can create a GUI that will wait for input. In this very answer you mention modal dialogs, which makes your answer very confusing. First you say you can't, then you say you can.